# WSO1 API Manager 2.1.0 active-active deployment not support distributed cache?

Tags: deployment, wso2-api-manager

API Manager version : 2.1.0

I want to configure wso2 apimanager as active-active deployment pattern.
In the document below, there is no clustering configuration of two nodes with wka (well-known-address).

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+an+Active-Active+Deployment

When I make this setting, (not set clustering)
I want to know whether the cache for the response is shared by each node or not
when using round-robin algorithm in LB.

If it is shared,
Even if I did not have a clustering configuration with wka, I want to know how it is shared.

If you know, I would appreciate your reply.